# How to make a html tag id into php string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm now building up a project and it have some errors and I'm not able to find them so help me out.
I have created a html file name (name.html) and a php file name (result.php) I have added some of Java when we click on Submit button it will take us to the result.php and display the text on an image through php my coding is like this.

For (name.html)

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" name="myname" placeholder="E.g: abc">
<input type="button" id="next" name="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

For (result.php)

```
<? php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'image.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$string = $_GET["name"];
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 115;
$y = 185;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

The problem is that when I'm clicking over submit button the Script take me to the page result.php and the text inside the Input tag is not being displayed.

Comment: When you press submit does the page you are sent to have the GET attributes you are expecting? If not you will need to post your Javascript.

Comment: do you have <form> tags + action of the form? Please correct your HTML code, because what you are saying can not happen in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example of working one

name.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="result.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="myname" placeholder="E.g: abc">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.php

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
$string = $_GET["myname"];
imagestring($im, 20, 5, 5,  $string, $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: If I want to add a customized

Comment: What do u means customized? Not understand.

Comment: If I want to give my own image suppose nooobody.jpeg so what for that

Comment: What if I don't want to include name in the input tag For Eg- <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" \placeholder="E.g: abc">

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little fix:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="result.php">
<input type="text" id="name" name="myname" placeholder="E.g: abc">
<input type="submit" id="next" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is my php $string= $_GET["name"]; for getting value from the text box

Comment: Thanks For helping Pleasure Meeting you

Comment: @NoooBody, please accept the answer or at least upvote if it was helpful

Comment: What if I don't want to include name in the input tag  For Eg- <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" \placeholder="E.g: abc">

Comment: the `id` is used mainly for javascript purposes, and the `name` attribute is submitted to the server and available for the php code